# Trying to parse array of arrays JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How would I go at parsing this JSON? Its an array of arrays; http://extradelar.se/match
I have been googling and trying for hours. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: What did you try? Hint.. nested for loops. Json deserializer.

Comment: Different snippets of code, using Convert.DeserializeObject<IList<Rootobject>>(json)..
I see

Comment: @LewsTherin, Ok I understand, could you please give me alittle bit of code help? I think I could manage if I just have something to work on :)

Comment: @user3581054 As your title says: it is an array of arrays... `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<YourObj>>>(json)` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObj[][]>(json);` What is so hard in it.

Comment: Thanks I will work on this!

Comment: none of the suggestion provided will work for the user because the Json given to him is structured incorrectly to begin with.

Comment: @AydinAdn I wouldn't be so sure since I tested it with http://jsonlint.com/ and then deserialized with Json.Net. I only didn't post an answer since I think the question is very poor and doesn't show any effort.

Comment: @L.B I'll keep it simple, prove it with an answer...

Comment: @AydinAdn Haha, Read my comment under your answer..

Comment: @user3581054 Better deserialize it to a generic dictionary `var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>>(json);`

Answer (score 2):

> prove it with an answer

**@Aydin Adn**, Are you happy? this is how you can write a working code. (*Sorry for posting it as an answer, since it is too big for being a comment.*)

```
var lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<MyObject>>>(jsonInQuestion);
```

---

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string match_id { get; set; }
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    public string clan_id { get; set; }
    public string hero_id { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string team { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string wins { get; set; }
    public string losses { get; set; }
    public string concedes { get; set; }
    public string concedevotes { get; set; }
    public string buybacks { get; set; }
    public string discos { get; set; }
    public string kicked { get; set; }
    public string pub_skill { get; set; }
    public string pub_count { get; set; }
    public string amm_solo_rating { get; set; }
    public string amm_solo_count { get; set; }
    public string amm_team_rating { get; set; }
    public string amm_team_count { get; set; }
    public string avg_score { get; set; }
    public string herokills { get; set; }
    public string herodmg { get; set; }
    public string heroexp { get; set; }
    public string herokillsgold { get; set; }
    public string heroassists { get; set; }
    public string deaths { get; set; }
    public string goldlost2death { get; set; }
    public string secs_dead { get; set; }
    public string teamcreepkills { get; set; }
    public string teamcreepdmg { get; set; }
    public string teamcreepexp { get; set; }
    public string teamcreepgold { get; set; }
    public string neutralcreepkills { get; set; }
    public string neutralcreepdmg { get; set; }
    public string neutralcreepexp { get; set; }
    public string neutralcreepgold { get; set; }
    public string bdmg { get; set; }
    public string bdmgexp { get; set; }
    public string razed { get; set; }
    public string bgold { get; set; }
    public string denies { get; set; }
    public string exp_denied { get; set; }
    public string gold { get; set; }
    public string gold_spent { get; set; }
    public string exp { get; set; }
    public string actions { get; set; }
    public string secs { get; set; }
    public string consumables { get; set; }
    public string wards { get; set; }
    public string time_earning_exp { get; set; }
    public string bloodlust { get; set; }
    public string doublekill { get; set; }
    public string triplekill { get; set; }
    public string quadkill { get; set; }
    public string annihilation { get; set; }
    public string ks3 { get; set; }
    public string ks4 { get; set; }
    public string ks5 { get; set; }
    public string ks6 { get; set; }
    public string ks7 { get; set; }
    public string ks8 { get; set; }
    public string ks9 { get; set; }
    public string ks10 { get; set; }
    public string ks15 { get; set; }
    public string smackdown { get; set; }
    public string humiliation { get; set; }
    public string nemesis { get; set; }
    public string retribution { get; set; }
    public string used_token { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And look at the result after testing... http://prntscr.com/503tgv

Comment: And this is what you should have got instead... http://i.imgur.com/dAfuXgX.png

Comment: @AydinAdn I think this not the place to show what *asnwers* do wrong :)

Comment: I'll leave this with you as a leaving thought... test your answer, are you capturing all the values? Why do you have a single class when you have data representing 4 different classes, for example, where's the ReplayUrl? or the ClanId? or the Slots labeled 1 to 5?

Comment: @AydinAdn Just join all of your classes..

Comment: And what about all the null values I'm now getting in between when I iterate through the array? Your answer is a replication of my answer now, your original answer, was actually wrong, it's now kinda right, but you still need to sort it and filter it into individual classes

Comment: @AydinAdn I just had showed a subset of all properties, since I had used the first line. I didn't say `JSON you're being sent isn't valid`.  Now I just added props chosing a new line, I may still be missing some properties but the idea is simple. It is valid json, it can be parsed, it has nothing in common with your poor linq in answer.

Comment: Yet it's 10 times better than what you've produced with your amazing naming convention

Comment: @AydinAdn So all you have to shoot is the naming convention? Lets leave it to OP. BTW: Since I am too lazy to convert json to c# I use  http://json2csharp.com/. You may try it too :)

Comment: @AydinAdn You always avoid on commenting `JSON you're being sent isn't valid.` It is **valid** Don't forget it.. BTW: You can also read my *Dictionary* solution which doesn't require any classes. Since it is a single line of code I posted as comment.

Comment: I said it isn't valid in the sense that it isn't structured correctly, the owner of the question would have missed out on tons of data because you couldn't be bothered to give him an answer that you've tested your self, so sure I'll remember giving the user an answer that both works for him, and is clean.